# Is there a special way to repair fiberglass bumper?

Tags: paint, bumper

My fiberglass bumper has cracks and is white.

This cars value is not much and I don't need it to be perfect.  I'm quite happy to just get it back to black with all the cracks and leave it at that.

However was also wanting to know:

a) If I did just paint this black can I just leave it at that or might it cause any problems later?

b) Is there a better easy and cheap diy way of repairing this? Is it different from plastic e.g. Do I need to\can I use a filler etc to fill in gaps as its fiberglass?

[image: pic 1]

[image]

Also what about those little circle paint chips, do I just apply a blob of black paint over them and that's the end of it?

Comment: I cannot see the image, but are you sure it's fiberglass? There are very few cars today which use fiberglass for *any type* of body panel. Are you wondering about flexible, non-metal bumper covers? If so, there is a question about it already on here. So you know, there is a different way to refinish flexible bumpers as they need a flexible paint (or flexible ingredients within the paint). If it cures hard like regular paint does, it will soon crack and flake off of a flexible bumper. I'll see if I can find the duplicate question for you.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 There's an exposed area in the bottom photo, which looks like GRP to me?

Comment: @NickC It's an aftermarket bumper and I was told its fiberglass but yeah, as you can see from the exposed bits they like it has been constructed from lots of straw/fibers.

Comment: @JamesWilson GRP and fibreglass are the same thing, the fibres you see are the glass, which is bonded together with resin. The repair kits I mentioned contain mats of glass-fibre and a bottle of resin and hardener

Comment: I'd agree ... those are fiberglass bumpers :o) Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can buy GRP repair kits, which include the resin, hardener, etc from most automotive supply shops - I wouldn't recommend just leaving it as the cracks will weaken the structure of the area. As @Paulster2 says though, check that it is indeed GRP (Fibreglass is a brand name...) - but it looks like it to me from the exposed area in the bottom photo.

Comment: what about the little white spots, do I just put a blob of paint there? thanks.

Comment: I'd spray over the whole area, it'll look neater.

Comment: not that it matters here but "fiberglass" is not a brand name. "fiberglas" (one s ) is trademarked by owens corning though.

Comment: @agentp - thanks, I was misinformed! GRP is still the correct term though ;)