# How to repair this side skirt?

Tags: body-work, dent

[image]

As you can see side skirt has been denting inwards and left side of it outwards a bit as a result.

How should I go about repairing this diy or is it better to get a replacement\give to garage?  if garage how would they go about fixing it and how long would it take to fix?

Comment: What picture? But this info may help : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/53515/10976

Comment: James, please add more detail to your questions. We cannot tell what you're thinking or what you're looking at. When the cliche goes a picture is worth a thousand words, they really aren't kidding. Please use *actual* pictures of what you are describing and we are going to be a lot more ready to help you. This not only goes for this question, but other questions you've asked recently. Really, we want to help ... you just aren't giving us much to go on.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I apologise I keep forgetting to upload the pictures.

Comment: Is this actual skirt (attached) or the rocker panel (part of the body)?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 in this diagram it is referred to as a side sill which I believe is the same as a side skirt?  https://www.hondapartsnow.com/parts-list/1999-honda-civic-2dr_si-ka-5mt/protector.html?PNC=2

Answer (score 1):

Since this is a bolt on piece, you can try to pull it down and fix it yourself. If you find you cannot get the job done, then go to the website you provided in the comments and buy the one which is prepainted. You'll find it is going to be *far cheaper* to do this yourself than taking it to a shop. It looks as though there are only two fasteners which old it on (front and back), so really, it shouldn't be a big deal to do the work yourself. It also looks as though the pieces from the website are already color matched, so no painting would be involved.

Comment: yes but how would I repair the dent, do I try to hammer it out, soak it in hot water and pull it out etc?  I think it's plastic.  How would a body shop fix it?

Comment: Do what you can ... whatever you think will work for you. Hammer may be too much if it's plastic. It may just pop right out. Soak it in hot water might help. If all else fails, just replace it. Take it off, though, to do it.